# How to use font face in Firefox ad-on when the site uses Content Policy Security?

Tags: javascript, css, firefox-addon, font-face, content-security-policy

I develop a Firefox add-on wich allow the user to modify the style of the website. He can choose to use a font of the extension.

Content Policy Security specify it should not interfere with the operation of browser add-ons or extensions installed by the user :
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Security_Policy#Browser_add-ons_and_extensions_exemption

When the website uses the directive "font-src" of Content Security Policy to not allowed cross domain font, it doesn't work.
I try to inject css on the content script of the add-on by this method :

```
var l = document.createElement('LINK');
l.rel = "stylesheet";
l.type = "text/css";
l.href = 'fontface.css';
this.head.appendChild(l);
```

Or by this method :

```
 s = '@font-face {
font-family: 'customfont';
src: url(data:application/x-font-ttf;charset=utf-8;base64, ... ) format('truetype');
}';
newStyle = document.createElement("style");
newStyle.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
newStyle.appendChild(document.createTextNode(s));
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(newStyle);
```

In both methods, I have in firebug the error :
"downloadable font: download not allowed ( {css code} )"

Is it possible to use custom font face in a Firefox add-on when the website have the CSP directive font-src ? How to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `contentaccessible=true` in the `chrome.manifest` file on the path that contains your file, unless its base64 then im not sure: https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/9406437#file-chrome-manifest-L1